# Android Swipe ListView - Delete item with internal button

Tags: android-listview

I followed [THIS](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/) tutorial to implement a swipe listview.

What I want to do is to use one of the buttons inside the list view to delete listview row.

I don't want to delete when I swipe (I know how to do it) I want the the listview row will delte just while the internal button will press.

My code is the same as in this tutorial.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user2235615, you just need to call your_listview.closeAnimate(item_position); after removing the data form the adapter. You will probably have to handle button1 onClick() outside the adapter for this.

I'm sorry for not answering directly to @user2235615 but I don't yet have the necessary rep to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer of this question:

In the "ItemAdapter.java" file I just added this 2 lines:

```
        remove(data.get(position));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So the onClick method should look like this:

```
   holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        remove(data.get(position));
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

But my problem now is that the SwipeListView deleted item doesn't closed. The item after the deleted one stay open.

I don't know why it's happened, I look for answer for this and the only thing that i found is to add the "notifyDataSetChanged();" line.

Is someone know why it's happened?

Comment: I think you should call  listView.dismiss(position); call remove().